# WordPress: How to add additional filters to the ones already found on the theme template?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

I have a theme that has color and price as product filters. I want to add 2 more filters.

I have tried using the WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter plugin but I'm not succeeding. I was expecting to add 2 more filters on top of the original ones.

Please Assist. Thank you in Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using plugin

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell what parameters would you like to filter and have you tried using different plugins? If you want to set variations as filters and use plugin, you can try Themify - WooCommerce Product Filter, set new filter configuration and use shortcode to put it into your page.